# GeoIP2 with Glassfish. Is it possible?

Tags: glassfish, geoip, java-ee-7

Is it possible to use GeoIP2 with Glassfish server? I use maven for GeoIP2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
    <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the following error:

```
SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app
SEVERE:   Undeployment failed for context 
SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Set<Service>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager(Set<Service>)]"
```

when I try to deploy the app.

UPDATE
I had to add this

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>15.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but this looks like an issue with the Google guava lib (have a look [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1433)).

Are you deploying to GlassFish 4? If so you can try to deploy your application on GlassFish 3 and see if that helps.

You can also try to exclude the guava lib in the following way:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
        <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>    
    </dependency>
```

Comment: `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>15.0</version>
        </dependency>` I had to add this